# Button with exactly the same code, produces two different styles

Tags: android, android-layout, listview, android-button

I have two different set of buttons, one in the activity and one inside a listview. They have very similar code, but display two different styles.

The header set of buttons code :

```
 <Button
        android:id="@+id/invoices_1year"
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="fill_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.2"
        android:onClick="refresh"
        android:text="@string/Invoices_1_year" />
```

while the Listview's buttons code is :

```
<Button
    android:id="@+id/invoiceButton"
    android:layout_width="0dp"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginLeft="10dp"
    android:layout_weight="0.25"
    android:text="View Pdf" />
```

The Xml for Listview for @ir2pid  :

```
<ListView
    android:id="@+id/InvoiceList"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
    android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
    android:layout_below="@+id/searchArea" />
```

The output I get on my device :

[image: Image of Whats displayed on device.]

My expected results is that both the button sets look the same.

Comment: you might be unknowingly applying a theme on the list view or the activity, also try looking in the styles.xml if there are any such overriding.

Comment: do you want same color?

Comment: Yeah, I want the same color. I will add the Xml for the listview to the orignal post.  I dont think i am applying a theme to the listview.

Comment: In each item of ListView, in Android Studio preview layout, did you see the button color is white

Comment: In android studio preview, they are the same color as the header buttons.

Comment: Try to use styles for all the button

Comment: Whenever i make a style for buttons , they lose the nice background(borders,coners etc) that they currently have. I will attempt to make another one.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In drawable folder create round.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<selector xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android" >
    <item android:state_pressed="true" >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#5e7974" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#e4d46f" android:endColor="#e4d079"  />
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item android:state_focused="true">
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#c7cf2d" />
            <solid android:color="#e9da67"/>
        </shape>
    </item>
    <item >
        <shape android:shape="rectangle"  >
            <corners android:radius="3dip" />
            <stroke android:width="1dip" android:color="#e7d851" />
            <gradient android:angle="-90" android:startColor="#e4d079" android:endColor="#87cf8d" />
        </shape>
    </item>
</selector>
```

And in button add

```
android:background="@drawable/round"
```

Answer (score 0):

Following Bala Raja answer , I found the generic material design button xml and modified it to only use my specified color.

This is my round.xml

```
<inset xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:insetLeft="@dimen/abc_button_inset_horizontal_material"
android:insetTop="@dimen/abc_button_inset_vertical_material"
android:insetRight="@dimen/abc_button_inset_horizontal_material"
android:insetBottom="@dimen/abc_button_inset_vertical_material">

<shape android:shape="rectangle">

    <corners android:radius="@dimen/abc_control_corner_material" />
    <solid android:color="@color/ButtonGray" /> // My CUSTOM COLOR
    <padding android:left="@dimen/abc_button_padding_horizontal_material"
        android:top="@dimen/abc_button_padding_vertical_material"
        android:right="@dimen/abc_button_padding_horizontal_material"
        android:bottom="@dimen/abc_button_padding_vertical_material" />
</shape>
```

and in the buttom xml change the backgorund to`android:background="@drawable/round"`